# Where to put config for ansible scripts whilst documenting which settings are required?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook yaml file that contains the following:

```
---
- vars:
    remote_application_path: /apps/application1
    local_project_path: ~/projects/application1
  hosts: Selective
  remote_user: me
```

I want to commit this into Git. Other users will have a different `remote_user` and a different `local_project_path`: where can I put these configuration variables whilst also making it clear to other users that they need to specifiy them?

Comment: You could use the inventory file to set variables. http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data .      Then it should be easy to set the required settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could intentionally leave them blank and ensure that your playbook/role fails. Once users will begin to investigate, they will see that these variables need to be defined.

Alternatively, you could use Ansible [prompts](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_prompts.html) to ask users for these variables at run time.

Finally, document this with wherever you have documentation for the rest of your project/product. It could be a documentation site, wiki, Readme.txt/md, whatever else you use.